# Why isn't my reputation updated with recent upvotes?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I've just received 8 upvotes for my answer, but I can only see +25 reputation; all other upvotes have no reputation increase.

[image: reputation snapshot]

Is this a delay in the reputation system's internal processes or is it expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you met the 200 [rep cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) from upvotes for the day.

You'll start getting rep again after the day changes.

Comment: @sll, note that although you will not get any more reputation from upvotes today, you'll continue to get +15 reputation for each *accepted* answer.

Answer (score 2):

You hit the reputation cap for the day.  You can only gain 200 rep for upvotes per day.

Per [your account page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485076/sll?tab=reputation) you have 215 for the day, 200 for upvotes and 15 for an accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks JNK! To be onest I wondered why 200 is limit because there are a lot of users which posting many great answers and 200 is too low bound, this is my point of view